# Why are both definite article ("les") and possessive determiners ("mes", "tes") used here for body parts?

Tags: grammaire, articles-definis

In [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43421/possessive-adjective-before-a-body-part) answer, I learned that with "correct" French, you aren't supposed to use possessive determiners for body parts ("ma tête, mes jambes"), but instead use a definite article ("la tête, les jambes"); but that in relaxed French, you might see possessive determiners used.

In [this](https://ici.tou.tv/salmigondis-et-compagnie/S01E06?lectureauto=1) TV show (around 0:54), a superhero needs a kid's help on doing a physical exercise called "The Airplane", and is giving instructions to a kid:

> Pour faire l'avion, je m'installe sur le dos, comme ceci. Je replie
> mes jambes et toi, tu vas appuyer tes hanches ici *(points to belly
> button)*, sur mes pieds. Et tu vas mettre tes main dans mes mains, et
> nous allons décoller et redescendre. Ça te va?

I'm curious why he sometimes avoids using a possessive determiner with a body part, and sometimes doesn't. For example, he avoids it when he says: "je m'installe sur le dos", but uses it when he says "Je replie mes jambes" (instead of "Je me replie les jambes").

---

Here is a bonus example that might be useful to have explained to me: in [this](https://ici.tou.tv/ari-cui-cui/S01E04?lectureauto=1) show for children (at about 1:35), a woman sings to the audience about her love of fixing things and making crafts:

> Avec **mes** deux mains mains mains, 
>  Avec **mes** dix doigts
> coquins,
>  Je fabrique brique brique
>  Je bricole colle
> colle
>  Des idées plein la caboche
>  Fabricoler c'est
> fastoche.

I'm wondering if she could have said "Avec les deux mains" and "Avec les dix doigts" instead, and if it would have the same meaning / connotation, or if there instead would have been a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this answer, I learned that with "correct" French, you aren't supposed to use possessive determiners for body parts ("ma tête, mes jambes"), but instead use a definite article ("la tête, les jambes").

The reply you quote didn't clearly stated this "rule<sup>1</sup>" only apply to sentence like:

> Elle aime masser ses jambes.

The reason is primarily to avoid ambiguity as *ses jambes* doesn't tell whose legs they are. That means the sentence is grammatically correct but its style would be improved/clarified by using a reflexive construction.

Using possessive determiners for body parts is certainly possible and correct in many cases.

What is generally considered incorrect is using a redundant determiner like in:

> Elle aime **se** masser **ses** jambes.

A similar redundancy is:

> **J**'ai mal à **ma** tête.

but it is less criticized. Redundancy is not forbidden in French. It can be used to emphasize something. It might also be used when talking to kids to make clearer what is said. Reciprocally, redundancy is what naturally comes to kids lips when talking.

The reason is only your own head can aches, not someone else's head so we use:

> J'ai mal à **la** tête.

About the forms you quoted:

1. *Je m'installe sur le dos* is the only possible way to tell it. The bogus *j'installe sur mon dos* would be missing a direct object: "I install on my back" (I install what?)
2. *Je replie mes jambes* is less easy to sort out. *Je me replie les jambes* would be grammatically irreprochable but doesn't happen to be idiomatic. That's not the case with *je me bouche les oreilles* which is equivalent to *je bouche mes oreilles*.
3. *Avec mes deux mains* and *avec les deux mains* are both idiomatic and in my opinion could have been used interchangeably.
4. On the other hand  *avec mes dix doigts* sounds better than *avec les dix doigts*. The last form might trigger the question: "which ones?"

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I wouldn't call it a rule but a mild recommendation</sub>

Comment: Your comment aout "Je me replie les james" is useful to me, to remind me that things can be grammatical, but still wrong only because it's unidiomatic. I'm still not 100% sure what counts as a "redundant determiner". I added another clip from a children's show, where a woman sings: "Avec mes deux mains" and " Avec mes dix droigts"; isn't "mes" in both cases redundant? If it is redundant, is it considered to be incorrect French?

Comment: Redundancy is rarely grammatically incorrect, if ever. These are more style recommendations and sometimes, emphasizing whose body parts it is about is definitely fine, like *avec mes deux mains* or *avec mes dix doigts*. One can even argue *deux* is redundant too as you can't have more ;-)  Note also that when talking to kids, we often use more redundancy to make the sentence clearer to them.

Comment: if you are willing, could you add this information to your answer? i had understood the "rule" too rigidly; i didn't know that redundancy is actually usually allowed; and that it can be done for emphasis; and that redundancy is actually encouraged in some contexts (eg kids shows) to make the meaning more clear.

Comment: @silph I don't see how avec mes deux mains is redundant?? She is not performing an action on her body....She is using her hands to "fabriquer".

Comment: @Lambie It's doubly redundant. *Deux* is redundant because *mes mains* already means both of them, unless I'm Kali ;-) and *mes* is redundant when we can just say *avec les mains*.

Comment: I don't think you can say "avec les mains" in this song. It would not work as a song. The point is for the kids to identify their own hands when they hear it. Je fabrique avec les mains? This is a kid's learning song so deux mains dix doigts. I don't think it is redundant, I think it's for practicing numbers.  It's only redundant for an adult but not for a very small child who is learning about deux mains and dix doigts. Numbers.

Comment: @Lambie I wrote: *It (redundancy) might also be used when talking to kids to make clearer what is said* so it looks like we agree here. I wouldn't necessarily rule out *avec les mains* with kids though:  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RzWrVeydL._SY413_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg

Answer (score 3):

This [rule](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43422/17649)  does not take into account exceptions that are dictated by context in which various parts of the same sort have to be differentiated.

In the last sentence,  if the article is used there is no  way to ensure whose hands are meant.
In the second sentence, "mes" (jambes) could have been "les": the rule is not applied in this case (you might refer to that usage as the lax way of speaking); "tes" (hanches) is understandable as there is an initial specification by a possessive (mes): "les hanches" could have an unclear ring as to whose hips are meant, although that is deducible. "Mes" (pieds) is necessary because otherwise is not clear whose feet you are talking about.

The verb "se replier" as meaning "to bend" does not exist in the language; so, in any case,  you can't say "se replier les jambes". The verb form "se replier" does exist but it is used in the context of  battles.

Comment: so are you saying that in "proper" French, you are still allowed to say "Je replie mes jambes", because "se replier les jambes" doesn't exist as an allowed usage for "replier"?

Comment: @silph "Se replier" is a pronominal verb that means "to retreat", only (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/replier), bar a figurative meaning apparently derived from the literal meaning.You are not allowed to say it, normally, see this (same link): "1. En partiulier. [L'obj. désigne une partie articulée de corps] Replier les bras, les jambes. Pour porter ce corps si léger, le héron a assez, il a trop d'une patte; il replie l'autre;". However, occasionally, it is said (ex. Allonge **tes** jambes sous les siennes. _but_ Allonge les jambes. )

Comment: @Lambie 1/ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=personne+n%27a%2Cpersonne+n%27ont&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersonne%20n%27a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersonne%20n%27ont%3B%2Cc0 // « personne n'ont » : que des faux positif; l'accord est solide, toujours le singulier. 2/ « se replier » **a un sens** psychologique. « Se replier est psychologique » est gauche.

Comment: @Lambie Alors pourquoi l'écrire de travers ? Pourquoi me forcer et le reste des utilisateurs à lire votre français véreux quand vous pouvez écrire proprement ? Vous vous imaginez que les apprenants vont deviner que ce n'est pas correct ? Non, il vont penser que ça l'est et vous copier. Votre façon de faire n'est pas digne de celle d'un enseignant.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne crois pas que mon anglais soit aussi mauvais que vous le faites. Il y a d'autres personnes qui le lisent et s'il y  avait tant de problèmes d'idiomatisme il y aurait bien quelqu'un pour m'en avertir. Mais vous vous trompez la plupart du temps. Encore une fois, sans rien vérifier, vous  me dites  « promulgate a term » is not idiomatic, et c'est faux ; ça fait maintenant de nombreuses fois que c'est arrivé. Je peux être patient, mais si en plus vous niez tout en bloc, il faut l'avouer, il y a de quoi vous trouver irritante.

Comment: @Lambie Je fais très très peu de fautes de frappe, je prend soin de l'écriture, mais je serais un « slob » complet quand on en vient à l'idiomaticité de l'anglais ? Non, je peux utiliser une tournure pas très idiomatique occasionnellement mais c'est tout.

Comment: @Lambie Je laisse les miens, je n'ai pas le temps de repasser tout ça, et il me font la publicité qu'ils me font.

Answer (score 1):

En complément aux réponses précédentes, on peut aussi jeter un coup d'oeil du côté de l'analyse du *Bon usage* dans sa section sur le déterminant : « Possessif ou article ».

> En principe, on remplace le déterminant possessif par l'article défini
> quand le rapport d'appartenance est évident (on parle souvent
> aujourd'hui d'*appartenance inaliénable*), notamment devant les noms
> désignant les parties du corps (d'un être humain ou d'un animal), les
> facultés intellectuelles.
>  [...]
>  On met le possessif : 1) quand
> le nom est accompagné d'un complément ou d'une épithète [ *Un Saxon étendu*, SA *tête blonde hors de l'eau* (A. DAUDET) ] ; 2) dans certaines formules traditionnelles [ *Il
> lui demanda* SA *main* = Il lui demanda d'être sa femme] ; 3) inversement, pour éviter la
> confusion avec des formules traditionnelles où on a l'article. [ *Donnez-moi* VOTRE *bras* (dit le médecin) (À distinguer de donner LE bras à qqn, pour que celui-ci s'y appuie.). ]
> Pour imiter la langue familière [...] *J'ai mal dans* MES *jointures*
> (COLETTE, *Fanal bleu*, p. 94). [...]
>  Sans raison particulière
> [...] *Gros-Alain et Georgette virent* [...] *René-Jeanfroncer* SES
> *sourcils* (HUGO) [...] — Comme on voit, la règle donnée ci-dessus est loin d'être appliquée strictement.
>  Dans d'autres cas, le rapport
> d'appartenance doit être indiqué, mais il est plus élégant de le
> marquer par un pronom personnel complément du verbe que par un
> possessif attaché au nom. *Un grand* [...] LUI *tirait* LES *oreilles*
> (COCTEAU, *Enfants terribles*)
>  [...]
>  Plus négligé encore
> paraît le fait d'exprimer à la fois le pronom personnel et le
> possessif. Cela, pourtant, n'est pas si rare dans la littérature : *Je
> voudrais bien savoir* [...] *si le grand Cyrus et le grand Attila* /
> SE *sont graissé* LEURS *peaux avec cet onguent-là* (HUGO).[...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, extraits choisis du §
> 609, notes et variation de la taille de la police omises, exemples présentés plus loin dans l'original ayant été intercalés ici entre crochets ]

Aucun de ces exemples n'est incorrect, on parle de choix moins élégants ou plus négligés encore. On peut s'éloigner de la norme, ce qui est parfois justifié, utile, et même quand ce ne l'est pas, ce n'est pas nécessairement incorrect, si hors-normes.

Et par la suite on déborde du sujet précis de la question et suit (au LBU) une analyse de subtilités où le possessif de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne est concurrencé par l'article indéfini avec l'antécédent représenté par le pronom *en* ; et la sélection d'un tour avec l'un ou l'autre peut être conditionnée par la nature de l'antécédent (animé humain, inaminé) et un ensemble de facteurs. La question s'analyse aussi sous l'angle d'usages portant sur le pronom comme [objet (indirect)](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43679) etc.

---

Je trouve vraiment difficile d'avoir une vue d'ensemble du sujet qui permettrait d'en faire une présentation qui serait systématique tout en étant aussi utile que celle trouvée dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43578) et le genre de question présenté là et [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43564) est du type qui permette de réfléchir à l'adéquation entre les choix faits et l'usage, confirmant qu'une simple règle comme celle présentée d'entrée de jeu en question, tout en donnant une idée, ne saurait suffire à décrire la diversité de ces usages, avec les parties du corps ou autrement.

Comment: n.b. L'exemple _J'ai mal dans MES jointures_, est-ce qu'il imite la langue familière uniquement à cause du possessif ou aussi vu le choix de préposition (_dans_) ? cc. Luke

Answer (score 0):

Question:
Why are both definite article (“les”) and possessive determiners (“mes”, “tes”) used here for body parts?

It depends on what you are saying:

The easiest way for a French learner to understand this rule about body parts is to think of this:

A)
She washes **her** hands in the kitchen sink.
I brush **my** teeth in the morning.
We wax **our** legs every Friday.
She combs **her** hair in the bathroom.

Etc. In other words, **when we do things to our bodies**, in English you use a possessive with a body part as in the examples above. Whereas in French,  **you shift the pronoun to the verb.**

Elle **se** lave les mains dans l'évier de la cuisine.
Je **me** brosse les dents le matin.
Nous **nous** épilons les jambes tous les vendredis.
Elle **se** peigne les cheveux dans la salle de bain.

B)
Obviously, sentences like:
**Your hands** are dirty, Johnny. Don't touch the food. do use possessive pronouns in French with body parts.

would be:
**Tes mains** sont sales, Johnny. [Ne] Touches pas à la nourriture. [informal often leaves off the ne in spoken French.]

If **your feet** are clean, you may walk on my white carpet barefoot!

Si **tes pieds** sont propres, tu peux marcher pieds nus sur mon tapis blanc !

Obviously, I have not covered every single usage, but it a learner learns the pronoun shift to the verb, they can get pretty far....

C)
**Also,** when you move parts of your body, and it's clear whom they  belong to in moving them (such as lift, lever; bend, plier; cross, croiser; turn, tourner; draw in, ramasser [dance]), French doesn't usually use any possessive:
Je lève les jambes pendant cet exercice-là.
Je plie les jambes quand je m'assieds.
Je croise les bras devant cette attitude.

These are movements that one does **TO parts of one's own body**:  lever, plier, croiser, tourner (la tête) etc. Why? There is logic here. Unless you are moving parts of someone's else body, there is no need for a possessive as they could not belong to anyone other than the antecedent person. In that sense, it's English that's weird: Lift your legs. or Turn your head.

But if you are telling someone to do those movements to those parts of their body, they **can** take a possessive:

- Levez **la/votre jambe** un peu plus pour bien faire le mouvement.
- Tournez **la/votre tête** vers la gauche.

etc.

[Please note: I have not dealt with complicated speech redundancies here. One step at a time.]