# « Y grimacent ou ben y s'ferment les yeux » en français soigné sans le pronom personnel de la phrase ni le possessif ?

Tags: québec, registre-familier, régionalismes, pronoms-personnels, registre-soutenu

> Le français du Midi utilise le tour avec le pronom personnel et
> l'article dans des cas où le français régulier userait du possessif,
> notamment pour des vêtements, etc. : "*Il s'est perdu* LE
> *parapluie*. Voir § 672, c.
>  Dans l'exemple suivant, qui représente l'usage populaire québécois, on trouve le **pronom personnel** là où le
> français soigné n'emploierait **ni ce pronom ni le possessif** : *Y
> grimacent ou ben y s'ferment les yeux* [quand le sang coule pendant un
> match de boxe] (M.-CI. BLAIS, *Un joualonais sa joualonie*, I).
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §
> 609 note R4 ; la note accompagne le paragraphe d'une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47065) se
> terminant par « [...] un possessif attaché au nom. » ]

- De quel pronom personnel parle-t-on ?
- Qu'aurait-on employé en français soigné qui n'est *ni ce pronom ni le
  possessif* dans la phrase de [Blais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie-Claire_Blais) ?

Answer (score 3):

On parle ici du pronom *se*. La phrase attendue est :

> *Ils grimacent ou bien ils ferment les yeux.*

Comment: On parle ici du pronom se? Oú dans la réponse se retrouve le pronom se?

Comment: "Dans l'exemple suivant, qui représente l'usage populaire québécois, on trouve le pronom personnel là où le français soigné n'emploierait ni ce pronom ni le possessif." Je parle du pronom *s'* qui apparaît dans l'exemple cité.

Comment: Pour rester dans le registre populaire, on aurait pu écrire : "*Y grimacent ou bien y ferment les yeux"*