# 2 questions on the sentence 'Nous gagnons bien notre vie'

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

**Question 1**

Why is it *notre vie* but not *nos vie**s***? Does *notre vie* imply that we are living together or cooperating, while *nos vies* imply that we have separate lives?

**Question 2**

Consider the sentences *Il se brosse les dents* and *Il a mal à l'estomac*. Here we do not say *ses dents* or *son estomac* as it is redundant. Then why do we say *notre vie* but not *la vie*?

Comment: *Vie* isn't a body part.  For the use of the possessive adjective please read https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43421/358 and https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43563/358.

Comment: @None Thank you for the SE links. They are quite helpful. According to the both links the natural tendency is to use possessive pronouns with body parts, but the children are forced not to use it that way as it results in redundancy. The thing is, I cannot see the difference between a body part and vie when it comes to using possessive pronouns with them redundantly.

Comment: @None 1- I edited the question and corrected 'à vie' as 'la vie'. 2- Can you provide sample contexts?

Comment: I suppose you mean sample contexts for *gagner nos vies/notre vie* ? I've deleted my comment since you correct *la vie*. As for your comment - I know it sounds silly to say that but I can't do better - *la vie* not being a body part we use the possessive adjective. Another thing I could say is that's the way we say it in French. Using the definite article would not make sense to to a French person.

Comment: Ok, so: gagner sa vie can be viewed as invariable. I was thinking in Spanish. ganarse la vida.

Comment: I am voting to close this with hopes it will be made into two different questions.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you say *nous gagnons bien nos vies* or *nous gagnons bien notre vie* is often context dependent, not always.

---

> Nous sommes six associés, une quinzaine de salariés. La demande est forte, nous gagnons bien notre vie. [An interview](https://www.rtl.fr/actu/politique/presidentielle-2017-zoom-sur-les-attentes-des-professions-liberales-7788166895)

Plural. Six different people living separate lives but each earning their living as associates in the same firm.

---

> Lorsque nous travaillons, il est vrai que nous gagnons bien nos vies. [A printed pamphlet](https://www.undia.fr/version1/pdf/Lettre_Ouverte_20180301.pdf).

A group of people each one of them earning a separate living.

---

> Nous travaillons tous les 2 et nous gagnons bien notre vie.
> [A forum](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/forum/affich-8460009-succession-et-deces).

Singular. A couple with two separate incomes. But plural would be just as acceptable.

---

> Nous gagnons bien nos vies et nous n'aurions aucun problème à lui venir en aide.  [A forum](https://amomama.fr/81664-mon-fils-de-16-ans-a-mis-une-fille-encei.html).

A couple, the plural implies they both earn a living but it can't be for certain.

---

> .. nous gagnons bien notre vie [Article printed in a magazine.](https://www.larvf.com/,portrait,10381,1104892.asp)

A couple working together, a common source of income. I would not expect the plural here.

---

> Ce genre de bien coûte une petite fortune, et Hugo se réjouit déjà du pourcentage qu'il va empocher. Nous gagnons bien nos vies, en particulier Hugo.  ([excerpt from a novel](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Moon_tome_1/LtIPEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22nous%20gagnons%20bien%20nos%20vies%22&pg=PT43&printsec=frontcover))

Plural, and no choice here because of the precisions given on the partner's income.

---

> Pour ce qui est du paiement, comme l'a dit Éloïse, nous gagnons bien nos vies, et nous souhaitons assumer nous-mêmes les frais de notre mariage. [Excerpt from a novel](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Quand_Tombent_Les_Masques/M9VSDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22nous%20gagnons%20bien%20nos%20vies%22&pg=PT227&printsec=frontcover)

Plural but singular possible here.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. How did you come up with so many examples that fast?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the first question only; the second one has been treated already in several preceding questions (see the linked questions).

In fact "gagnons bien nos vies" is not used at all in print: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gagnons+bien+nos+vies%2Cgagnons+bien+notre+vie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgagnons%20bien%20notre%20vie%3B%2Cc0). It  does not mean that nobody will ever use it in their speech; occasionally someone might say that because the context implies that several livings are concerned. We have a similar situation in English; mostly, English speaking people choose to say "we earn our living", but a few say "our livings": [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earn+our+living%2Cearn+our+livings&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearn%20our%20living%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearn%20our%20livings%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cearn%20our%20living%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearn%20our%20livings%3B%2Cc0). It just happens that the French feel somewhat more strongly that "vie" should be in the singular, or possibly that they have acquired a stronger habit somehow. It's nothing more than an idiomatic particularity. I must say that to my ear "nous gagnons bien nos vies" does not sound usual; however it doesn't sound illogical.
Here "vie" has to be taken as "means of livelihood" (living); nevertheless there is  no implication of collaboration: what is meant is "chacun d'entre nous gagne bien sa vie".

Answer (score 1):

On Question 1, this reflects the fact in situations where English has what is called a "distributive plural", French has a tendency to use the singular.

For example,

- Ils ont tous enlevé **leur chapeau**

corresponds to

- They all took off **their hats**.

In this case, each person has *one* hat. Considering the totality of hats would suggest the plural, whereas considering what each person has suggests the singular.

Even in English, there is a degree of variation, and one of the cases where you have a greater likelihood of finding a distributive singular is in idioms. In English, you'd never say "They can't put their fingers on what's wrong." The idiom is "to put one's finger on something," and this outweighs the fact that "they" collectively have many fingers. Of course, *gagner sa vie* is an idiom, which makes it even less likely to appear with a distributive plural in French.

With all of this being said, you do find the distributive plural in French. You can say

- J'ai regardé **leurs ventres/leur ventre.**